# Extending IOException

Tags: java, exception

I have an exception (`MalformedDataException`) which extends `IOException`. Somewhere in the code it is thrown and it is temporarily 'caught' by the main class, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedDataException { ... }
```

But **what is an input/output exception exactly?** When does it have to be thrown? Should it be extended?

The Oracle docs do not *explain* anything about it.

Comment: An input/output exception is an exception that arises during input or output. The Oracle does indeed say something about that. Not a real question.

Comment: 1) When the normal flow of app don't happen, then throw exception 2) Yes you can extend exception to be more declarative and add functionality if you want.

Comment: @EJP Why is it not a real question? And what do the Oracle docs say?

Comment: "Signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred. This class is the general class of exceptions produced by failed or interrupted I/O operations." [oracle-docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)

Comment: @KonstantinWeitz Yeah, but what are considered to be input/output operations? User input? Hardware input? An error in the data format of an incoming byte stream over the internet?

Comment: I don't think you should inherit from IOException, I would inherit from IllegalArgumentException, like [jdom](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/IllegalDataException.html)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing much of a question here.  Pretty much any exception class can be extended by anyone and thrown by anyone.  What it "means" is pretty much up to the thrower (though one hopes that they attempt to be consistent with the meaning of the base class).

Comment: @HotLicks Edwin Buck just managed to answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An input / output exception is something that has messed up normal input and output operations.  It is purposefully vague to cover a large variety of scenarios, including reading from a file that was closed, to reading from a file that was removed, to reading from a socket that was closed, to just about anything that could go wrong reading or writing to anything.

If you write code that can recover from a failure (like a network connection that attempts to reconnect on a bad read), you should catch the `IOException` and perform the "recovery" procedure to continue processing.  If you don't actually recover from a failure, you should (probably) just allow the `IOException` to rise up to the next level by marking the method `throws IOException`.

Capturing `IOExceptions` and doing nothing with them is a recipe for really bad bugs that are hard to debug.  You have been warned.  Don't do it.

You should not extend an `IOException` unless you have a rare situation where your "new" exception to be thrown is subject to failures that stem from input / output instability.  In the case of `MalformedDataException`, the reason it is thrown is because you read something from the input that doesn't even look like what you expected.

Since input and output typically is subject to line interference, there is some controversy as to whether an `IOException` is appropriate for malformed data.  I personally lean on the "not appropriate" side of things, as it will tend to lead people to questioning the integrity of the line, instead of the integrity of the data.

Comment: Actually, in your example the "main" method doesn't catch the `Exception` it allows the exception to bubble up into the JVM (which will shutdown the JVM.  You might want to invest some time with a beginning Java tutorial, as you probably are guessing that Java acts far more like a language you are more familiar with.  Sometimes Java does act like other languages, but where it is different, sometimes it only _looks_ like other languages.

Comment: Okay, this is what I was looking for. Bad question (see the comments and downvote on question) still yields a good answer. Thanks!

Comment: As a reaction on your first comment - I know the main doesn't catch the exception, that's why I put apostrophes around it. But I did not know how to call it. ;-)